# When compiling through Makefile, getting some errors while copying a file

Tags: linux, makefile

On Linux, when compiling through Makefile, I get some errors while copying a target:

```
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
     $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
     chmod 775 $(ETARGET) $(OBJ)
     $(shell cp libTrgt.a ../../../../lib)
```

During this makefile is giving an error

> cp: cannot stat `libTrgt.a': No such file or directory,

even though I see it is there in the current directory.

When I split it in two targets, it succeeds and I am not sure why:

```
all: $(TARGET) COPY

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
     $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
     chmod 775 $(ETARGET) $(OBJ)

COPY:
     $(shell cp libTrgt.a ../../../../lib)
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: `$(shell pwd ; cp libT...)`: does it prints what you'd expect?

Comment: that's working fine... as I mentioned in the second part when I did in steps it is succeeding, COPY has the same command $(shell cp libTrgt.a ../../../../lib), it is working fine.

Comment: Is `libTrgt.a` the target of your rule?

Comment: yes.. libTrgt.a is the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `$(shell ...)` command is executing while parsing the Makefile, whereas the commands to create the library `$(AR)` is executing later on.

At the time the copy command is executed, the library file does not exist. Yet.

You should more simply write your Makefile as:

```
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
     $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
     chmod 775 $(ETARGET) $(OBJ)
     cp libTrgt.a ../../../../lib/
```